# Dropping list of procedures

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to drop a list of procedures after when **ALL** of these procedures are executed successfully. So that if there is any of the procedure is failed then it can be debugged without being dropped.

However, I am getting ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object

Here is the code.

Package specs:

```
create or replace package remove_procedures AUTHID CURRENT_USER is

procedure dropProcedures(p_schema varchar2, p_type varchar2, p_object_list varchar2);
procedure dropProceduresName(p_schema varchar2, p_object_list varchar2);

end remove_procedures;
```

Package body:

```
create or replace package body remove_procedures is

-- type declaration for a collection of string
type t_stringtab is table of varchar2(100);

function listToTab (p_list in varchar2)
  return t_stringtab is
  l_str varchar2(32760) default p_list ||',';
  l_n number;
  l_retval t_stringtab   := t_stringtab();
  l_item varchar2(100);
begin
  -- traverse the items in the comma seperated list into a nested table
  loop
    -- find the position of the first comma in l_str
    l_n := instr( l_str, ',' );
    -- exit the loop if a comma was not found
    exit when (nvl(l_n,0) = 0);
    -- add an element to our collection to hold the next item parsed from the string
    l_retval.extend;
    -- parse the next item from the comma seperated string
    l_item := ltrim(rtrim(substr(l_str,1,l_n-1)));
    -- raise an exception if the length of the item exceeds 30 bytes (limit for oracle object names)
    -- todo - add check for violations of other naming rules e.g. items beginning with a number
    /* if lengthb(l_item) > 30 then
      raise_application_error(-20000,'Error : 30 bytes limit exceeded for item : '|| l_item);  --disabling this block for file names
    end if; */
    -- otherwise add the item to the element in the collection
    l_retval( l_retval.count ) := l_item;
    -- reset l_str variable to the remainder of the comma seperated list
    l_str := substr( l_str, l_n+1 );
  end loop;
  return l_retval;
end listToTab;

procedure dropProcedures(p_schema varchar2, p_type varchar2, p_object_list varchar2) is
  l_objects t_stringtab := t_stringtab();
  l_object_found number;
begin
  l_objects := listToTab(p_object_list);
  for i in l_objects.first .. l_objects.last loop
    select count(*) into l_object_found
    from user_objects
    where upper(object_type) = upper(p_type)
    and upper(object_name) = upper(l_objects(i));
    if l_object_found = 0 then
      dbms_output.put_line('WARNING : Object '||upper(p_schema)||'.'||upper(l_objects(i))||' does not exist.');
    else
      dbms_output.put_line('Dropping Object '||upper(p_type)||' named '||upper(p_schema)||'.'||upper(l_objects(i))||' now...');
      begin
        execute immediate 'drop '||p_type||' '||upper(p_schema)||'.'||upper(l_objects(i));
      exception when others then
        if sqlcode = -00942 then
          null;
        else
          raise;
        end if;
      end;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

Then here is the code to run all procedures, and if all procedures are executed then drop a few procedures.

```
create or replace procedure ref_master is
begin
    ref_categories;
    ref_country;
    ref_currency;
    ref_currency_to_country;
    promotions.remove_procedures.dropProcedures(
        p_schema => 'PROMOTIONS', 
        p_type => 'PROCEDURE', 
        p_object_list => 'ref_country,ref_currency,ref_currency_to_country'); 
end;
```

And here is execution of the ref_master, and this is where I get the error mentioned earlier:

```
begin
  -- Call the procedure
  ref_master;
end;
```

Surprisingly, when I run only a certain lines then it works quote ok:

```
begin
promotions.remove_procedures.dropProcedures(
        p_schema => 'PROMOTIONS', 
        p_type => 'PROCEDURE', 
        p_object_list => 'ref_country,ref_currency,ref_currency_to_country'); 
end;
```

Any ideas how can I proceed so I will be able to drop the procedures if all executed successfully, or stop immediately if any of the procedure didn't execute properly. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Why do you want to drop the procedures after they've run? Procedures aren't supposed to be one-shot things,

Comment: Yes, but the client says that they tend to change the procedures, so if the mentioned procedures in the list aren't dropped then there can be many many obsolete procedures in future.

Comment: Still sounds wrong. Why does "change" mean `drop`? Why not `create or replace`?

Comment: by change, I mean not using that procedure anymore. Sorry for not being very clear

Comment: In which case my first point applies. It seems like your client probably isn't using procedures correctly. But the customer is always right, eh :)

Comment: It may help you to know which object is locked. Use the V$LOCKED_OBJECT view joined to the DBA_ALL_OBJECTS view using the OBJECT_ID. You may find that one of the procedures is being used (and therefore locked).

Comment: Write the procedure code in one single [anonymous block](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/overview.htm#LNPLS141) instead of packages/stored procedures. Because no packages/stored procedures are created in the database nothing needs to be cleaned-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrote the right code to do what you expect: there is an exception when executing one of your procedures, and Oracle stops immediately.

But there is an issue in one of the procedure you run before the deletion, it takes too long and  you get and exception:

> ```
> ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object
> ```

What output do you get from

```
set time on

exec ref_categories;
 exec dbms_output.put_line('ref_categories:ok');
exec ref_country;
 exec dbms_output.put_line('ref_country:ok');
exec ref_currency;
 exec dbms_output.put_line('ref_currency:ok');
exec ref_currency_to_country;
 exec dbms_output.put_line('ref_currency_to_country:ok');
exec promotions.remove_procedures.dropProcedures(
    p_schema => 'PROMOTIONS', 
    p_type => 'PROCEDURE', 
    p_object_list => 'ref_country,ref_currency,ref_currency_to_country');
```

?

My analyze is one of the procedure takes too much time (and you get this "timeout") because a table or something is locked by another Oracle action ( `insert`, `update`, ...). But we cannot guess.

What you can do is while your procedure runs, explore database sessions (with proper tool, e.g. TOAD, PL/SQL Developer), and see what object(s) is locked.

## Edit:

We could minimalize your issue like:

```
create or replace procedure test
is 
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('done');
end;
/

begin
  test;
  execute immediate 'drop procedure test';
end;
```

You get this error because the procedure cannot be dropped from within the scope they are called from.

## solution is to have 2 distinct calls: launch procedures, then launch deletion.

For `sqlplus` to avoid deletion if procedures didn't run right, use the `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK`; like this (tested)

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK

create or replace procedure test
is
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('done');
end;
/

begin
  test;
end;
/
begin
  execute immediate 'drop procedure test';
end;
/
```

## from PLSQL Dev,

I found what you where looking for I think: ***`execute immediate` to call your procedures***:

```
begin
  execute immediate 'begin test; end;';
  execute immediate 'drop procedure test';
end;
/
```